# Select count from a table where the value = another table value

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables

```
table_a:
column_1|column_2
1       |250
2       |325
3       |420
4       |160


table_b:
column_1|column_2
a       |1
b       |2
c       |3
d       |4
```

There is a foreign key linking table_a.column_1 with tabl_b.column_2 from .

I need to select count from table_a.column_2 where table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_2.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `count`  and not the `sum`? Can you share the expected result?

Comment: I just insert these 4 rows but its count, in that case it should return 1

Comment: table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_2 corresponds to 4 rows in your exemple so the count will return 4

Comment: Please explain why you think it should return 1.

Comment: oracle (oracle 11) or MySQL? Very likely not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from table_a a
join table_b b on a.column_1 = b.column_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a join and a count(a.*) like this

```
select 'table_a.*',count('table_b.column_1') 
from 'table_a' 
left join table_b on table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_2 
group by table_a.column_1
```

It would give you all fields from table_a and then the count of coincidences in table_b in last field. You can name that column like this:

```
  count('table_b.column_1') as 'nameColumn'
```

Hope it helps